# creating a contact page in HTML and PHP can getting a return error when testing (HTML 500)

Tags: php, html

So I am rather new to coding in these languages, I am getting a good understanding of how to write in them but not how to troubleshoot well. I went on and found some videos and read some sites to understand how to get this to work, and got this
HTML

```
<form id="Contact-form" method="post" action="contactform.php">
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your Name" class="form-control" required>
<input type="text" name="Mail" placeholder="Your E-mail" class="form-control" required>
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Subject" class="form-control" required>
<textarea name="message" placeholder="Message" rows="7" class="form-control" required></textarea>
<button class="form-control submit" type="submit" name="sumbit"> Send message</button>
```

The PHP

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){{
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $subject = $_POST['subject'];
    $mailFrom = $_POST['mail'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    
    $mailTo = "myhostprovided@email"
    $headers = "From: ".$mailFrom;
    $txt = "You have received an e-mail from " .$name. ".\n\n".$message;
        
        
    mail($name, $subject, $txt, $headers);
    header("Location: Contact.php?mailsend")
   }
```

I have it live and attempted to test send myself an email and I get a basic error (HTML Error 500) and no email, it changes the URL to "contactform.php" as expected. I followed the tutorials to the T, what am I doing wrong!
Thank you for the help in advance

Comment: please retry by changing {{    to {

Comment: I retried with that, I also moved it to above the $mail(name,....) line. I don't know if it matters but I am getting a "(T_Variable)" error on the $headers line. I also made sure to clear my Chache before trying...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please change the codes from

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){{
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $subject = $_POST['subject'];
    $mailFrom = $_POST['mail'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    
    $mailTo = "myhostprovided@email"
    $headers = "From: ".$mailFrom;
    $txt = "You have received an e-mail from " .$name. ".\n\n".$message;
        
        
    mail($name, $subject, $txt, $headers);
    header("Location: Contact.php?mailsend")
   }
```

to

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $subject = $_POST['subject'];
    $mailFrom = $_POST['mail'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    
    $mailTo = "myhostprovided@email";
    $headers = "From: ".$mailFrom;
    $txt = "You have received an e-mail from " .$name. ".\n\n".$message;
        
        
    mail($name, $subject, $txt, $headers);
    header("Location: Contact.php?mailsend");
   }
```

Comment: Okay, weirdly I moved the "<?php" to above the code and outside a set of code I had commented out and it brought me to a new page (the page was just a white page with the code written out.) so I am going to assume it worked, I can't access my that email correctly because I am stupid, but I think this helped thank you!

Comment: So, As I said I believe this was the fix, but now that is redirecting the client to a blank page, how would I have them redirect to the page they were at before? or the index page? would I need to add a Js script or add to my PHP lines

Comment: you may add <script>window.location.href="xxxxx.php";</script> at the end of your codes to do the redirection.

Comment: Okay cool, thanks I should really read more on PHP before I continue PHP is so foreign to me lol

Comment: The <script> is javascript. So please add them after you terminate the PHP by adding a ?> tag